# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Another SimpleCache instance uses the folder:

Tags: java, android

I have this Error 
**" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Another SimpleCache instance uses the folder:"** 
i am working with SimpleExoPlayer and this error show when i try to open the video for second time 
how to close or delete the previous simplecache ?
and this is my code :

```
 SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView = findViewById(R.id.video_view);

        SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, new DefaultTrackSelector(new DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder().build()));

        SimpleCache downloadCache = new SimpleCache(new File(getCacheDir(), "exoCache"), new NoOpCacheEvictor());

        String uri = "http://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb/bbb_1280x720_60fps_6000k.mp4";

        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new CacheDataSourceFactory(downloadCache, new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, "seyed"));

        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(uri));

        player.prepare(mediaSource);

        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);

        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Comment: This happens because you're creating more than one active instance of `SimpleCache`. The first instance has to be either released or re-used.

Comment: how to released / destroy / close it ?

Answer (score 32):

You need to make your cache class `Singleton` to make sure you have one instance of `SimpleCache` across all your application:

```
public class VideoCache {
    private static SimpleCache sDownloadCache;

    public static SimpleCache getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sDownloadCache == null) sDownloadCache = new SimpleCache(new File(context.getCacheDir(), "exoCache"), new NoOpCacheEvictor(), new ExoDatabaseProvider(context));
        return sDownloadCache;
    }
}
```

And use it in your code like:

```
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new CacheDataSourceFactory(VideoCache.getInstance(this), new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, "seyed"));
```

Answer (score 14):

Making the `cache` object singleton does not necessarily solve the problem because the `cache` can still be locked due to a previous audio player call. When this happens, the `IllegalStateException` will still be thrown.

To solve this, you need to release the `cache` when releasing the player, i.e. put this in the overridden `release` method of the player:

```
        cache.release();
        cache = null;
```

Comment: I was correctly using the singleton pattern but still had issues with the instance & playback (completely random though). This `cache = null` was very important in my case because the call to `cache.release` was successful & the activity was destroyed & recreated but the Application instance was not. So when I used the same instance to cache & play the media, it failed with `IllegalStateException` (no crash, silent failure) which was internally validating if the `SimpleCache` instance was released or not.