# Exoplayer cache instance

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have implemented a video player in an application which uses `ExoPlayer` for playing and caching videos and it works well. Since all samples I found are using a singleton instance of [SimpleCache](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/cache/SimpleCache.html), I also followed this pattern and implemented it using singleton. But I want to know that is it safe for `SimpleCache` instance to be a singleton? or should I [release](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/upstream/cache/Cache.html#release()) it when user exits video player and create a new instance when user opens the video player?

Answer (score 0):

As at least two other SO questions discuss this. It is recommended to do this as a backup to singleton or as a main part of the workflow this kind of release of cache:

```
simpleCache.release();
```

[Error in Listening exoDownloadManager : Another SimpleCache instance uses the folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74641476/error-in-listening-exodownloadmanager-another-simplecache-instance-uses-the-fo)

[java.lang.IllegalStateException: Another SimpleCache instance uses the folder:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507270/java-lang-illegalstateexception-another-simplecache-instance-uses-the-folder)