# Error in Listening exoDownloadManager : Another SimpleCache instance uses the folder

Tags: java, android, download, media, exoplayer

Recently i have succeded to implement [downloading media](https://exoplayer.dev/downloading-media.html) of exoplayer. Here is the picture that illustrates needed classes to implement downloading media using exoplayer.

[image]

And according to [suggestion](https://ochornmapromise.medium.com/downloading-media-through-exoplayer-part-1-24b1767f07f1) of a fellow developer in medium and i quote:

> In order to make the DownloadManager be shared across all components of the app you can initialize it a custom application class. Exoplayer also advised that ExoDatabaseProvider should be a singleton and that download cache should not evict media.

Everything is working the way they should. Here Is my code in full..

DownloadService class :

```
public class ExoDownloadService extends DownloadService {
private final String TAG = "serviceTAG";


public ExoDownloadService() {
    super(
            1,
            DEFAULT_FOREGROUND_NOTIFICATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL,
            "download_channel",
            R.string.app_name, 0);
}


@Override
protected DownloadManager getDownloadManager() {
    final DownloadManager downloadManager = downloadManager();

    downloadManager.addListener(
            new TerminalStateNotificationHelper(
                    this, getDownloadNotificationHelper(this), 2));
    return downloadManager;
}

@Inject
DownCache downCache;


private DownloadManager downloadManager() {
    return ((HiltApplication) getApplication()).downloadMngContainer.getDownloadManager();
}


DownloadNotificationHelper downloadNotificationHelper;

public DownloadNotificationHelper getDownloadNotificationHelper(Context context) {
    if (downloadNotificationHelper == null) {
        downloadNotificationHelper =
                new DownloadNotificationHelper(context, "download_channel");
    }
    return downloadNotificationHelper;
}

@Nullable
@Override
protected Scheduler getScheduler() {
    return Util.SDK_INT >= 21 ? new PlatformScheduler(this, 1) : null;
}

@Override
protected Notification getForegroundNotification(List<Download> downloads, int notMetRequirements) {
    final DownloadNotificationHelper downloadNotificationHelper =
            new DownloadNotificationHelper(this, "download_channel");
    return downloadNotificationHelper.buildProgressNotification(
            this,
            R.drawable.ic_download,
            null,
            null,
            downloads,
            notMetRequirements);
}

private static final class TerminalStateNotificationHelper implements DownloadManager.Listener {

    private final Context context;
    private final DownloadNotificationHelper notificationHelper;

    private int nextNotificationId;

    public TerminalStateNotificationHelper(
            Context context, DownloadNotificationHelper notificationHelper, int firstNotificationId) {
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
        this.notificationHelper = notificationHelper;
        nextNotificationId = firstNotificationId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadChanged(DownloadManager downloadManager, Download download, @Nullable Exception finalException) {
        Notification notification;
        if (download.state == Download.STATE_COMPLETED) {
            notification =
                    notificationHelper.buildDownloadCompletedNotification(
                            context,
                            R.drawable.ic_download_done,
                            /* contentIntent= */ null,
                            Util.fromUtf8Bytes(download.request.data));

        } else if (download.state == Download.STATE_FAILED) {
            notification =
                    notificationHelper.buildDownloadFailedNotification(
                            context,
                            R.drawable.ic_download_done,
                            /* contentIntent= */ null,
                            Util.fromUtf8Bytes(download.request.data));
        } else {
            return;
        }
        NotificationUtil.setNotification(context, nextNotificationId++, notification);
    }
}
```

}

DownloadManager in application..

```
public class HiltApplication extends Application {
public DownloadManagerContainer downloadMngContainer;
private final String TAG = "hiltTAG";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    downloadMngContainer = new DownloadManagerContainer(getApplicationContext());
   }
 }
```

DownloadManagerContainer class code..

```
public class DownloadManagerContainer {
private final Context context;
private DataSource.Factory httpDataSourceFactory;
private DownloadManager downloadManager;

public DownloadManagerContainer(final Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public DownloadManager getDownloadManager() {
    if (downloadManager == null) {
        downloadManager = new DownloadManager(
                context,
                getDatabaseProvider(context),
                DownCache.newInstance(context),
                getHttpDataSourceFactory(), //upstreamFactory
                Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6));
    }
    return downloadManager;
}

private DatabaseProvider getDatabaseProvider(Context context) {
    return new StandaloneDatabaseProvider(context);
}

public DataSource.Factory getHttpDataSourceFactory() {
    if (httpDataSourceFactory == null) {
        @Nullable CronetEngine cronetEngine = CronetUtil.buildCronetEngine(context);
        if (cronetEngine != null) {
            httpDataSourceFactory = new CronetDataSource.Factory(cronetEngine, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
        }
        if (httpDataSourceFactory == null) {
            final CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
            cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ORIGINAL_SERVER);
            CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
            httpDataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory();
        }
    }
    return httpDataSourceFactory;
}
```

}

DownCache class as singleton is :

```
public class DownCache {
private static Cache downCache;

public static Cache newInstance(final Context context) {
    if (downCache == null) {
        final File downloadContentDirectory = new File(getDownloadDirectory(context), "downloads");
        downCache = new SimpleCache(downloadContentDirectory, new NoOpCacheEvictor(), getDatabaseProvider(context));
    }
    return downCache;
}


private static File getDownloadDirectory(Context context) {
    File downloadDirectory = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
    if (downloadDirectory == null) {
        downloadDirectory = context.getFilesDir();
    }
    return downloadDirectory;
}

private static DatabaseProvider getDatabaseProvider(Context context) {
    return new StandaloneDatabaseProvider(context);
}
```

}

***The Problem :***

When in my fragment that i trigger download i also listen to downloadmanager to update UI: Here is my fragment code..

```
private void downloadMedia() {

    final Requirements requirements = new Requirements(Requirements.DEVICE_STORAGE_NOT_LOW);
    final boolean isRequired = requirements.checkRequirements(requireContext());
    DownloadService.sendSetRequirements(
            requireContext(),
            ExoDownloadService.class,
            requirements,
            isForeGround
    );
    Log.d(TAG, "Download Requirement Status Is : " + isRequired);
    if (isRequired) {
        try {
            final DownloadRequest request = new DownloadRequest.Builder(downloadID, Uri.parse(vidUrl)).build();
            DownloadService.sendAddDownload(requireContext(), ExoDownloadService.class, request, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "downloadMedia Error Is : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    downloadListener();
}


private boolean isDownloading = true;

private void downloadListener() {
    final DownloadManager downloadManager = ((HiltApplication) requireActivity().getApplication()).downloadMngContainer.getDownloadManager();
    displayDownloadProgress(downloadManager);

    downloadManager.addListener(new DownloadManager.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitialized(DownloadManager downloadManager) {
            DownloadManager.Listener.super.onInitialized(downloadManager);
            Log.d(TAG, "This Is onInitialized()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDownloadsPausedChanged(DownloadManager downloadManager, boolean downloadsPaused) {
            DownloadManager.Listener.super.onDownloadsPausedChanged(downloadManager, downloadsPaused);
            Log.d(TAG, "This Is onDownloadsPausedChanged()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDownloadChanged(DownloadManager downloadManager, Download download, @Nullable Exception finalException) {
            DownloadManager.Listener.super.onDownloadChanged(downloadManager, download, finalException);
            Log.d(TAG, "This Is onDownloadChanged()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDownloadRemoved(DownloadManager downloadManager, Download download) {
            DownloadManager.Listener.super.onDownloadRemoved(downloadManager, download);
            Log.d(TAG, "This Is onDownloadRemoved()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onIdle(DownloadManager downloadManager) {
            DownloadManager.Listener.super.onIdle(downloadManager);
            Log.d(TAG, "This Is onIdle()");
            isDownloading = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequirementsStateChanged(DownloadManager downloadManager, Requirements requirements, int notMetRequirements) {
            DownloadManager.Listener.super.onRequirementsStateChanged(downloadManager, requirements, notMetRequirements);
            Log.d(TAG, "This Is onRequirementsStateChanged()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onWaitingForRequirementsChanged(DownloadManager downloadManager, boolean waitingForRequirements) {
            DownloadManager.Listener.super.onWaitingForRequirementsChanged(downloadManager, waitingForRequirements);
            Log.d(TAG, "This Is onWaitingForRequirementsChanged()");
        }
    });
}

private void displayDownloadProgress(DownloadManager downloadManager) {
    final ExecutorService thread = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    thread.execute(() -> {
        final int size = downloadManager.getCurrentDownloads().size();
        Log.d(TAG, "Download List Is : " + downloadManager.getCurrentDownloads().size());
        while (isDownloading) {
            try {
                final float percent = downloadManager.getCurrentDownloads().get(size - 1).getPercentDownloaded();
                final String percentStr = Float.toString(percent);
                handler.post(() -> {
                    binding.tvDownPercent.setText(percentStr);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Percentage Is : " + percentStr);
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "displayDownloadProgress Error Is : " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
}
```

i face this **ERROR** which says: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Another SimpleCache instance uses the folder:* poiting to this line of code in "DownCache.class"`

```
downCache = new SimpleCache(downloadContentDirectory, new NoOpCacheEvictor(), getDatabaseProvider(context));
```

[Here it says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52508156/13634739) we should use `SimpleCache` as singleton, i did the precise instruction and yet facing the same Error. Where did i do wrong??

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem before.
My situation is when I tried to download the same audio second times, the simpleCache **used at same file directory path** is not released.

The answer that using SimpleCache as singleton you mentioned about, there is **create a cache file path with getCacheDir()**, not a specified file location.

If you want to use a specified file path, you'll need to release the SimpleCache object you used before.

```
simpleCache.release();
```

In my case, I create a array to save the downloading simpleCache...

```
private static SparseArray<SimpleCache> mediaCaches;

//Need to release the Cache that use in the same file path.
SimpleCache simpleCache = CacheUtil.getMediaCache(downloadMediaId);
if (simpleCache != null) {
    simpleCache.release();
}

simpleCache = new SimpleCache(file, new NoOpCacheEvictor(), new ExoDatabaseProvider(context));

//when I download a new audio episode, save with key:episodeId & value:simpleCahe
mediaCaches.put(downloadMediaId, mediaCache);
```

Comment: I have tried it but did not work. beside, could you tell me where should i put `downCache.release()` ?

Comment: @StackOverflower I have edited my answer with a simple example, I save the simpleCache when download a new episode, you can consider how to save your simpleCache which must be the same cache you used in the same file path.

Comment: Thanks dud but i solved my problem using dagger/hilt. i was  just curious why using singleton did not work properly.